# Need to draw domain of $f(x,y) = \ln(\frac xy) + \sqrt {\arccos {\frac {x-3y}{x+y}}}$

Tags: functions

I think i successfuly calculated domain but the problem is i dont know how to draw it. Confusing part is with arccos because you have 2 options because of fraction.

Comment: Add your results to the questions, i. e. write down the calculated domain.

Comment: @martini ok will do, give me a sec please.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Set $u=\frac xy$, we have
$$z=\ln u+\sqrt{\arccos\left(\frac{u-3}{u+1}\right)}.$$ We have
$$u>0$$
and 
$$\left | \frac{u-3}{u+1}\right|\le 1$$

Also
$$\arccos\left(\frac{u-3}{u+1}\right)\ge 0$$